# How to drop and create only tables which are changed in Code First - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using Code First approach in Entity Framework.

I have created a custom database initializer as below.

```
public class CustomInit : IDatabaseInitializer<APIContext>
    {
        public void InitializeDatabase(APIContext context)
        {
            bool dbExists;

            dbExists = context.Database.Exists();

            if (dbExists)
            {
                // remove all tables
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                   "EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = \"DROP TABLE ?\"");

                // create all tables
                var dbCreationScript = ((IObjectContextAdapter)
                       context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript();
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(dbCreationScript);

                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("No database is present");
            }
        }
    }
```

As per the above code, all tables in database is dropped and recreated.

What I need to do is to drop and create tables/entity which are changed in Code
like - adding or removing any column etc.

Is there anyway we can do this?

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Why are not [migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx) used?

Comment: @IvanR.I have never used Migrations. It would be kind of you if you can guide me on how I can implement migrations to find solution to my question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx) to update the database scheme.

1. Open **Package Manager Console** (Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console)
2. Run **Enable-Migration** command
3. Change your model
4. Run **Add-Migration** command in Package Manager Console.
5. Run **Update-Database** command to apply your model changes to the database.

Of course you should not use your custom database initializer.

Comment: Adding to your answer.. To make initial migration work, your database should be empty/not created.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to add this initialization to your in your context's constructor:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext>());
```

This will check your model against the database every time you run your program, and automatically drop and re-create the database if the model has been modified.

If you don't want to drop the database, and simply update it, then you can use the following initialization:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Config>());
```

Be advised however, **neither of these work in Entity Framework Core**, as Microsoft haven't and don't intend to implement automatic migrations for the .Net Core version.

Comment: I tried this. But now changes are not reflected in db. I added new entity but table isnt created for entity.

Comment: When I execute project, It throws error saying "There is already an object named 'xyz' in the database. "

Comment: @DheerajKumar Does modifying existing entities work? I think these initializations only update existing tables, but dont create new ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can revert back to initial migration which you have applied by updating the database.

**Update-database -targetMigration "MigrationName"**

Above command reverts all the db changes whatever you have applied as part of EF migrations.